# Examples in Topological Space

Tags: general-topology

> **$T_3$ Axiom.** If $\forall x\in X$, $F$ is closed in $X$: $x\in F^c$, $\exists U\in\mathcal{U(x)}$, $V\in\mathcal{V(x)}$, s.t. $U\cap V=\emptyset$, we call $X$ is $T_3$ space.
>
> ---
>
> **$T_4$ Axiom.** If $\forall F_1$, $F_2$ is closed in $X$: $F_1\cap F_2=\emptyset$, $\exists U\in\mathcal{U(F_1)}$, $V\in\mathcal{V(F_2)}$, s.t. $U\cap V=\emptyset$, we call $X$ is $T_4$ space.

Is there any relation between $T_3$ and $T_4$ without some restrictions on $X$? Or could someone give examples to show there is a space which is $T_3$ but not $T_4$, and conversely. Thank you.

Comment: You should look into *Counterexamples in Topology* bt Steen and Seebach

Comment: a classic example is the sorgenfrey plane.

Comment: An interesting site for these types of questions can be found here: http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146 . It's a searchable database for "Counterexamples in Topology."